# How do I autosave an array in a js file along with some text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a .js file that contains an array that will be imported as data. For example, it will look like this:

```
const ideasData = [
    {
        content:"Content",
        title: "This Title",
        date: new Date()
    },
    {
        content:"content2",
        title: "second title",
        date: new Date()
    }
]

export default ideasData
```

The export is necessary since I will import the data in another file. I use the data in the program and then will modify it throughout.

```
import ideasData from "./ideasData";
class Ideas extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            ideas : ideasData
        }}}
```

I want to overwrite the data in the file in a similar format(the array, then the export) every couple seconds as an autosave. So next time I open the webpage it will look like when it was closed.

I put a function `autoSave()` in the class and then `setInterval(this.autoSave, 5000)` in the render method before the return. I am not sure how to save the array, `this.state.ideas` to the ideasData file. Also, I am not sure about putting the setInterval in the render method. I changed it to `setInterval(console.log("saved"),5000)` and it seems to have only logged that in the console once.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: You could export a "set" method that updates the array as you save it. So when autoSave runs, it just sends the data to set, which updates the cached information

Comment: Your code doesn't represent the core of your question. Does the issue you're having is with the `setInterval`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky this isn't a file cache, it's just using a program cache

Comment: @Jabberwocky the data is not downloaded by a user, it is saved to a local file

Comment: @LahelLight to clarify on Jabberwocky's point, you're using node to save the file to the local file system correct?

Comment: @GalAbra State is created with data from file "ideasData.js". I want to be able to save the data in the state at regular intervals to the file "ideasData.js". So when I refresh the page, it will load the data from ideasData to state.

Comment: @zfrisch I think so, yes. I want the server to have a file stored in the server that it updates if that makes sense?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Like this? `function set(newIdeasData){ideasData = newIdeasData}` in the ideasData.js (stores data) file, then in the main file `autoSave() {set(this.state.ideas)}`. But how would I export both the array and the function?

Comment: @LahelLight yes :) I explained in more detail in an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we already have your file here:

```
const ideasData = [
    {
        content:"Content",
        title: "This Title",
        date: new Date()
    },
    {
        content:"content2",
        title: "second title",
        date: new Date()
    }
]

export default ideasData
```

Now, all you have to do is export a set method (in the same file as the code above) such as:

```
export function update(newData) {
    ideasData = newData;
}
```

You will have to change `const` to `let` in order to mutate it, otherwise you can just clear it and push the new data in, or you could create a Class with it's own state. Either way.

Now, when `setInterval(this.autoSave, 5000)` runs, just import the new `update` function as well, and call `update(this.state.ideas)` to update your data cache.

Comment: How do I import it? Like this?

`import ideasData from "./ideasData";`
`import update from "./ideasData"`

Since I already imported the data from this file. Also, I just pasted the "export function update(newdata)" at the end of the ideasData file. Does that work?

Comment: Importing will be a little different since one is a default export and the other is a regular. I believe it would be more like `import ideasData, { update } from "./ideasData";`

Comment: Hm, there's no more errors anymore, but my file isn't updating. I put the setinterval inside a componentDidMount like this: `componentDidMount(){setInterval(this.autoSave,5000)}`. I replaced it with a `console.log("saved")` and that just consoled when I refreshed and only once.

Comment: Try some debugging -- does the function have proper binding so it knows what context of `this` to use?

Comment: I binded both `autoSave` and `componentDidMount` to `this`. But I think setInterval does not run properly? I changed it to `componentDidMount(){setInterval(console.log(Math.random()),1000)}` to test it. But my console only has one log in it